# contour integral with integration by parts

Tags: contour-integration, branch-cuts

Is there a complex version of integration-by-part? I saw someone used it but didn't find it in textbook. I tested integrals $\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x-2}\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\log(x-2)}{x+1}\mathrm{d}x$, where $\mathcal{C}$ encloses both -1 and 2. But the results do not match. Is it because they are not equal at the first place or I chose the wrong branch cut?

Answer (score 4):

Integration by parts is just the product rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But you need well-defined analytic functions on your contour, which you don't have here.

Comment: Not everyone would agree in your answer. Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/505865/622884 for example.

Comment: @DrPotato Looks to me as if Daniel said exactly the same thing, using the word “holomorphic” instead of “analytic.”

Comment: (+1) This looks like a good answer. There is no analytic extension of $\log(x+1)$ onto a contour that has a non-zero winding number around $-1$. The same goes for $\log(x-2)$ and $2$.

Comment: Yes Ted you're right. So is there any alternative for contour integration by parts when the contour encloses some poles or singularities?

Comment: @DrPotato For each integrand to be a well-defined holomorphic/analytic function on the closed contour, every function appearing must have the sum of residues equal to $0$ inside.